# When does the platform does not support ssl? (QSslSocket::supportsSsl() returns false)

Tags: windows, qt, openssl, qsslsocket

I am an qt app developer which uses https to connect to rest api. I deploy ssl dll libraries together with application (the same version as the qt was built with) but sometimes on windows it happens, that users report to me that the internet connection within my app is not working. While debugging, I find out that qsslSocket::supportsSsl returns false and openssl version in use is empty string. When this happen? The user can use his internet browser and send me email. What can be the issue?

Comment: Just my tow cents, could it be failing machines have SSL already installed and Qt tries to load incompatible dll version at runtime instead of yours? How do you ensure the SSL libraries deployed by you are first in the PATH in all systems?

Comment: Based on what I found, the libraries next to the exe file should be loaded first. Am I wrong?